# Is function point analysis still used for estimates?

Tags: project-management, project-planning, function-points

In one discussion among colleagues I have heard that function point analysis is not used nowadays since it can go wrong for various reasons.

So WBS (work breakdown structure) is used commonly.

Is that true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function Points and WBS are two different, but related items.  Function Points is a unit of measurement that can be used to determine complexity and work effort, WBS (work breakdown structure) is an approach to define sub units to a project (problem).
SO, when starting a project with a given scope and set of expectations, you use a WBS to define the sub units of the project (to a degree that is useful for you), once you have well defined sub units, you can determine the work effort by assigning function points to each and multiplying velocity (# of function points per day that can be delivered- as an example).

Here are some useful links:

- [Function Points via Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point_analysis)
- [Software Sizing During Requirements Analysis](http://www.modernanalyst.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/115/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/512/Software-Sizing-During-Requirements-Analysis.aspx)
- [WBS via Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_breakdown_structure)
- [step by step WBS](http://www.hyperthot.com/pm_wbs.htm)

Comment: +1 for good explanations of the involved theories
-1 for not answering the question

Answer (score 1):

I just took the introductory course of a project management program, and we didn't even look at "function point analysis" (I'm not sure what that is), but we spent a lot of time looking at WBS.  All the following processes referred back to the WBS.

Answer (score 1):

I can only talk about what I have seen. I have seen IBM use Function Points in Mexico to determine product size and pay subcontractors.

Regards...

Answer (score 1):

I did function point analysis back in university in the early nineties, but it never came up again once I actually entered the work force.

Answer (score 0):

Function Points have gone out of fashion, but they do work very well.   I urge you to look further at the work of Capers Jones who has published some terrific books that help bring measurement and certainty to software projects.

Answer (score 0):

FPA is **not** an effort estimation technique itself. FPA is used to determine the 'functional size' of requirements to a software, expressed in 'function points' (fp), thus can be one of many input variables for a more complex effort estimation model (such as COCOMO).

Do not mistake 'estimation' for 'planning'. WBS is a planning technique, that requires detailed knowledge on what and how to build/develop. In contrast, estimation is a forecast of expected effort/costs based on limited facts.

So it's not about 'one-or-the-other' but rather 'when-what'.